# I'm Developing an Android app and using Firebase as my Backend

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

By Using Firebase , all my Logic will be inside the client app . 
So if someone got my source code by reverse  engineering the android app , then he/she can easily change the Firebase References (node names) and can change things of other users and that's not a good thing at all.

My app uses Phone Authentication to authenticate Users .  but The hacker can change the reference  and then authenticate himself using his phone no  and then he is good to go altering someone else's account .

So how to prevent that ?

Comment: Do you keep sensitive data inside of the app?

Comment: Im talking about the References..  Any one has my code can change the node names ,  Then he can edit that node

Comment: I'm not familiar with Firebase - but maybe keep these _node names_ at the server with the authentication session

Comment: *firebaser here* As Thomas' answered: use Firebase's server-side security rules to control what a user can access. Each user is identified with a `UID` in there, which cannot be hacked (short of the user sharing their credentials, or you leaking the server credentials for your project).

Comment: Thanks Thomas.   Can you please show me snippets about the rules how to use them.

Comment: @Vincent. Check out my answer. As I stated there, your q was too broad to give a concrete snippet. That's why I linked you to the firebase docs where some example usages are shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right, you are using firebase database. You shoud read how [firebase security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) work. It is possible to let a user only access and modify his own data if the user is authenticated via one of [Firebase auth's methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) (you mentioned phone auth). As you haven't provide example code, I can't give you a concrete usage, but you can find many examples in the [firebase docs about "Securing user data"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security).

If you do it like this, it doesn't matter what a "hacker" would do as he needs to authenticate with another user's number first. (=impossible)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Progaurd](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)  to obfuscate your code.You can find more on [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Configuring-ProGuard) link

Comment: 1) Proguard just obfuscates your code. With enough time, it can be reverted. 2) It isn't possible for a malicious party to modify another person's firebase data if Firebase Rules are used correctly. It has nothing to do with obfuscating the code