# Firebase Push Notification - How to show multiline message in Notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Getting Push Notification's `message` only in a *single line*, whereas I was expecting it in `multiple lines` with `BigPictureStyle` and *Base* (both the Notification styles).

See the attached *Screenshot*, whereas in this image, we are just showing `"Hello from Firebase Cloud Messaging"` so this fits in single line itself.

But the fact is, If I am trying to show *"Hello from Firebase Cloud Messaging and again Hello from Firebase Cloud Messaging"* even then I am getting Message in `single line only` with *three dots* at the end like this *...*

[image]

Here is the required `part` of the *code*, I am using:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(image)
                        .setBigContentTitle(messageTitle)
                        .setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(messageBody)
                        .toString()))/*Notification with Image*/
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

*NOTE:* Same issue, I am facing whenever, I am *sending message without Big Image* (Base / Simple Push Notification)

See this *screenshot*:

[image]

So, the *only concern* is **How to show multiline message in Notification ?**.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45415413/4026792

Comment: You can show multiple line using @Dus answer...But with bigPictureSyle it will always have single line

Comment: I have a code for firebase notification which shows big image along with text. Logic is, I used to send notification ID number in fcm notification to app. `onMessageReceived` App communicates with my web app by sending that ID number and downloads the data related with that notification id present in my web app and shows the same in notification builder. If you want I can post the code here so that you can refer.

Comment: @MohammedFarhan Yes please... my pleasure

Answer (score 12):

You almost had it, you just need to set the [bigText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigTextStyle.html#bigText(java.lang.CharSequence)) property.

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
    bigTextStyle.setBigContentTitle("Title");
    bigTextStyle.bigText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," +
            " sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. " +
            "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris " +
            "nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in.");

    notificationBuilder.setStyle(bigTextStyle);

    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager)
            getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyMgr.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
```

[image: multiline]

Comment: so what about the big image ?

Comment: @Sophie sorry, i don't think you can add the big image with the full text.

Comment: Why on earth was this upvoted?? The title of the post is about "multiline message". This solution doesn't show multiline. I have yet to see a working example of multi-line on Android 11. Seems that Google disabled all HTML markup for notifications.

Answer (score 5):

try this:-

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
        context);
Notification notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
        .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
        .setContentText(message).build();

notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use your own layout:

```
Builder builder = new Builder(context);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.star_white)
builder.setAutoCancel(true)
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);

RemoteViews remoteViewsBig = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_big);
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_small);
remoteViewsBig.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.banner, bitmap);

remoteViewsBig.setTextViewText(R.id.button, data.getButtonText());
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.button, data.getButtonText());

remoteViewsBig.setTextViewText(R.id.text_title, data.getTitle());
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_title, data.getTitle());

remoteViewsBig.setTextViewText(R.id.text_content, data.getContent());
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_content, data.getContent());

builder.setCustomContentView(remoteViews);
builder.setCustomBigContentView(remoteViewsBig);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
```

And xml files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@color/custom_blue_gray_800"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            tools:text="Title"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:text="text\ntext\ntext"
            />

    </LinearLayout >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/button_main"
        android:text="Click"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        />

</LinearLayout >
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@color/custom_blue_gray_800"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:paddingLeft="12dp"
              android:paddingRight="12dp"
              android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/notification_small" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />


</LinearLayout >
```

Answer (score 2):

You can show multiple line using @Dus answer...But with `bigPictureSyle` it will always have single line in setSummaryText method and other option is to create `RemoteView` and implement the UI as per your required design

For `RemoteView` Refer [this](https://medium.com/@britt.barak/notifications-part-3-going-custom-31c31609f314)

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is used to you.
Check this:

```
   NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context);
    Notification notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setContentText(message).build();

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Refer this link: [Display Notification in multiline](https://tips.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-showing-push-notification-in-multiline/)

Thank you...

Comment: what about the big image ?

Comment: Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
     .setContentTitle("New photo from " + sender.toString())
     .setContentText(subject)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_post)
     .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
     .setStyle(new Notification.BigPictureStyle()
         .bigPicture(aBigBitmap))
     .build();

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigPictureStyle.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how i manage to show big image and some multi line texts in notification. This is working code in my project.

There are 2 kind of fcm messages in fcm. `Display Messages` and `Data Messages`. And am using `Data Messages` to handle fcm notification in foreground and in background.

```
  /**
 * Created by Mohammed Farhan on 01-08-2017.
 */

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService
{

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    private AppAuth auth;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {
    }




        /*To check if remoteMessage is empty, if not empty then read the id from "title" field*/
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0)
        {
            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            String title = data.get("title");
            sendNotification(title);
            Log.d(TAG, title.toString());
        }

    }


    private void sendNotification(String title)
    {


        final String id = title;

        /* Here DataFromServer is custom method, used to sync data from my server. It has interface method to listen it when data sync and adding it to local sql completes*/
        DataFromServer dataFromServer = new DataFromServer(this);
        dataFromServer.setDataLoadCompleteListener(new DataLoadCompleteListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void dataLoadComplete()
            {

            /*AppNotificationDAO is a class which  has many DAO(Data Access Object) method. I have used DAO to make ease in saving,querying data from local sql*/
                AppNotificationDAO appNotificationDAO = new AppNotificationDAO(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this);

                /*getAppNotificationByID is DAO method which does server communication and fetch data from it based on Id(Here its notificationId)*/
                AppNotification appNotification = appNotificationDAO.getAppNotificationByID(Long.valueOf(id));
                if (appNotification != null)
                {
                    if (appNotification.getPhoto().equalsIgnoreCase("NA"))
                    {
                    /* photo is a field in my AppNotification class and getPhoto() is getter  and appNotification.getPhoto() returns the value stored in it. Here am using it to save url of image related to notification in my web app*/

                        /*if url is not present then below method displays just a text as notification*/
                        showBigTextStyleNotification(appNotification);
                    }
                    else
                    {


                    /*if there is url then am running asyncTask to get bitmap of that image and show it in notification tray along with text. Below method does that*/
                        new showBigPictureStyleNotification(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this,
                                appNotification.getMessage(),
                                Links.NOTIFICATION_IMAGE + "/" + appNotification.getPhoto(), appNotification)
                                .execute();

                                /* am passing some variables inside above methods, and Links is a class where have defined some strings (links) to my webapp*/
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        dataFromServer.getAppNotificationFromServer(Long.valueOf(id));




    }

    private void displayNotification(AppNotification appNotification)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, NotificationListActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri notificationSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle("KSP_PQRS");
        builder.setContentText(appNotification.getSubject());
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification);
        builder.setSound(notificationSoundUri);
        builder.build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());
    }

    private void showBigTextStyleNotification(AppNotification appNotification)
    {
        Bitmap icon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.police_logo);

        android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(appNotification.getSubject())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.police_logo)
                .setLargeIcon(icon1)
                .setContentText(appNotification.getMessage());

        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        bigText.bigText(appNotification.getMessage());
        bigText.setBigContentTitle(appNotification.getSubject());
        bigText.setSummaryText(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        mBuilder.setStyle(bigText);
        mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
        mBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);

        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent;
        if (appNotification.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("GEN"))
        {
            resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationListActivity.class);
        }
        else
        {
            resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        }

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder
                .create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder
                .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(((int) appNotification.getId()) + 1000, mBuilder.build());
    }

    private class showBigPictureStyleNotification extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
    {
        private Context mContext;
        private String title, message, imageUrl;
        AppNotification appNotification;

        showBigPictureStyleNotification(Context context, String message, String imageUrl, AppNotification appNotification)
        {
            super();
            this.mContext = context;
            this.title = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
            this.message = message;
            this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            this.appNotification = appNotification;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            InputStream in;
            try
            {
                auth = new AppAuthDAO(mContext).getAppAuth();
                byte[] toEncrypt = (auth.getUsername() + ":" + auth.getPassword() + ":" + auth.getDeviceId()).getBytes();
                String encryptedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(toEncrypt, Base64.NO_WRAP);

                URL url = new URL(this.imageUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encryptedCredentials);
                connection.connect();
                in = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                return myBitmap;
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Intent intent;
            if (appNotification.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("GEN"))
            {
                intent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationListActivity.class);
            }

            else
            {
                intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
            }

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(appNotification.getSubject())
                    .setTicker(message)
                    .setSubText(message)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.police_logo)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.police_logo))

                    /*using setStyle am setting big image along with some lines of text in notifications*/
                    .setStyle(new Notification.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(result))
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .build();
            notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notificationManager.notify(((int) appNotification.getId()) + 1000, notif);
        }
    }
}
```