# Firebase override default click on notification event android

Tags: java, android

I am developing an application using Firebase Messaging. When my app is in the backgroud, I can receive notification and when the user taps on the notification, it default opens my application (which jumps to main activity)

SplashActivity is the main activity and it lives only 3 seconds and it immediately starts MainScreenActivity

SplashActivity(Main which gets the firebase message payload via getIntent) -> MainScreenActivity

When notification is clicked, I want my app to open DetailActivity, so I do like this
Notification clicked -> SplashActivity received payload -> localbroadcast. MainScreenActivity received broadcast then open DetailActivity (I DetailActivity is opened from MainActivity) - > DetailActivity.

But the app behaves like this which I dont want
Notification clicked -> SlashActivity -> MainActivity -> DetailActivity -> MainActivity

I can get the payload by these code

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
    for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
        String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
        Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
        startOtherActivity();
    }
}
```

I want to open "OtherActivity" When users tap on the notification. I do get the log (payload) and I can start an "OtherActivity" when user tap on the notification. But the thing is it jumps to "OtherActivity" then suddenly it jumps back to my MainActivity. I guess it jumps to my MainActivity as default, how can I remove that default behavior?

I only can get the payload in MainActivity via getIntent(). How can I get the payload in other activity because my main activity is SplashActivity and it only lives 3 seconds

Comment: Share code of both activity

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/45415413/4026792